# (Rails newbie) How to deploy a ruby on rails application to Droplet?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I currently created a droplet with Digital Ocean and I am having trouble understanding how to deploy my ruby on rails application. 
I used DO one click option and that gave me a folder called rails_project. I currently have my rails application on github and plan to clone the repository to the root. Can I delete rails_project once I have my app on there?
Is there anything else I need to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you used Heroku before? If so, you could try Dokku with DO. Although you need to setup several things, you finally end up deploying to DO as you do to Heroku: git push dokku master.

Answer (score 0):

I'd check the `rails_project` app for `database.yml` to see how they connect to Postgres, but according to [the tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-ruby-on-rails-one-click-application-on-digitalocean), all the software you need should be installed.

I use [capistrano to deploy to DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorial_series/how-to-use-capistrano-to-automate-deployments), but if all you need to do is `git clone` / `git pull`, you should be fine.